# Standard c library headers on iPhone/iPod touch/iPad

Tags: iphone, c, gcc, ipad, jailbreak

I have an iPod touch and iPad with gcc installed on them. However, everytime I try to compile my programs they always fail. I am trying to write c programs for the terminal, not GUI. I am missing the standard c/c++ libraries (stdio.h, etc.). Can anyone tell me where I can find these libraries?

Comment: I'm guessing your developing for jailbroken devices right?

Comment: Reinstall gcc.  How can the standard libraries be missing?

Comment: i just reinstalled gcc and it didn't change anything. the gcc installation only includes float.h, stdarg.h, stddef.h and litmits.h. the rest of the standard libraries are missing. also I am using 3.2 and installing with cydia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system, with a vanilla install, the headers are here:

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/usr/include/
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/include/

And the libraries are here:

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/usr/lib/
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/lib/

Edit:

The headers are not on the device.  You will have to copy them over.  The libraries should all be on the device.

Comment: This is working thanks except now I'm getting a linking error

Comment: You could start a new question with more details about the new error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write command-line programs for the official iOS SDK.

Comment: I'm looking to write apps for jail broken devices